# Error When Testing Archlinux with Ansible Molecule

Tags: docker, ansible, archlinux

I'm trying to add support for Archlinux to my various Ansible roles. I'm trying to test the roles using Ansible Molecule. All the other distros are working fine with Molecule but I'm running an this error with Molecule when testing Archlinux. Here are the technical details:

**molecule.yml**

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
  options:
    role-file: requirements.yml
    requirements-file: requirements.yml
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
  - name: Archlinux-Latest
    image: megabytelabs/ansible-molecule-archlinux:latest
    command: /sbin/init
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    priviledged: true
    pre_build_image: true
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  connection_options:
    ansible_connection: docker
    ansible_password: ansible
    ansible_ssh_user: ansible
  inventory:
    group_vars:
      all:
        docker_molecule_test: true
  options:
    vvv: true
  playbooks:
    converge: converge.yml
verifier:
  name: ansible
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM archlinux:latest
LABEL maintainer="help@megabyte.space"

ENV container docker

# Source: https://github.com/CarloDePieri/docker-archlinux-systemd/blob/master/Dockerfile
# Source: https://github.com/CarloDePieri/docker-archlinux-ansible/blob/master/Dockerfile

RUN set -ex \
  && pacman -Syu --noconfirm \
      python \
      sudo \
  && pacman -Scc --noconfirm \
  && (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; \
      for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
      rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*; \
      rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*; \
      rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
      rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
      rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
      rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*; \
      rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*; \
  mkdir -p /etc/ansible \
  && echo -e '[local]\nlocalhost ansible_connection=local' > /etc/ansible/hosts \
  && groupadd -r ansible \
  && useradd -m -g ansible ansible \
  && usermod -aG wheel ansible \
  && sed -i "/^%wheel/s/ALL\$/NOPASSWD:ALL/g" /etc/sudoers

VOLUME ["/sys/fs/cgroup", "/tmp", "/run"]

CMD ["/usr/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

And here is the error I'm receiving:

**ERROR OUTPUT**

```
fatal: [Archlinux-Latest]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory.In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618893314.958555-25046-129222695615155 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1618893314.958555-25046-129222695615155=\"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618893314.958555-25046-129222695615155 `\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}
```

Note: I was experiencing a similar issue with Fedora 33 but the issue seemed to magically disappear over the course of a couple months.

Any advice is greatly appreciated - even ideas on what to check would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t mount the `cgroup` in the platform `volumes` entry, or mount them with read-write.

## Investigation

My molecule tests used to pass using Docker. I started seeing the same error. The issue started appearing with `archlinux:base-devel-20210404.0.18927`.

- `archlinux:base-devel-20210328.0.18194` Tests PASS
- `archlinux:base-devel-20210404.0.18927` Tests FAIL

Running the system upgrades on `archlinux:base-devel-20210328.0.18194` before to run molecule, tests FAIL.

```dockerfile
FROM archlinux:base-devel-20210328.0.18194

RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm python
```

Thus, it comes from a system change between 2021-03-28 and 2021-04-04.

Diffing the packages between both images, ignoring packages unlikely to cause this issue, I see that `systemd`, `systemd-libs` and `systemd-sysvcompat` were upgraded from 247.4-2 to 248-2.

Bingo! Building:

```dockerfile
FROM archlinux:base-devel-20210328.0.18194

RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm python --ignore systemd,systemd-libs,systemd-sysvcompat
```

Tests PASS.

I’m no `systemd` expert, it would take me more time than I’m willing to spend on this issue to dig further. The following changelog caught my eye and may be the source of the change. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v248/NEWS#L432-L435. I would be curious if others have the explanation.